# Possible to sign offline transactions with Geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, cold-storage, signature

I'd like to set up a cold storage wallet that has the ability to create and sign transactions offline. It seems both [Icebox](https://github.com/ConsenSys/icebox) and [ethkey](https://gavofyork.gitbooks.io/turboethereum/content/cold_wallet_storage_device.html) has this functionality, but I'd prefer to have the option to easily move the keys into Mist at a future date, without importing the raw private key.

So, naturally that brings me to Geth. [This](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/693/how-can-i-sign-a-piece-of-data-with-the-private-key-of-an-ethereum-address) post shows it's possible to sign arbitrary data with an RPC call, but what about an entire transaction? Is there a specific method for this, or is it just a matter of throwing in the correct raw data?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!