# how to sign with the Ethereum private key and derive the the r, v, s it needs for verification

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, signature

I know this kind of questions has been asked before, I want to know the detailed procedure to sign on msgs and derive the r, v, s(the command line), and the client and environment it needs to do the signing, thanks.
（I now use mist）

Comment: What more do you need to know than what's been described: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/693/how-can-i-sign-a-piece-of-data-with-the-private-key-of-an-ethereum-address  and http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2256/ethereum-ecrecover-signature-verification-and-encryption?lq=1

Comment: I use mist, and I keep failing installing geth. mist works fine with developing and deploying contracts, but when I get to this signature part, I get confused. maybe first some suggestions on installing geth on windows, very thank U!

Comment: Depending on your platform, Mist includes geth.  For instructions on how to install Geth, see: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Building-Ethereum

Comment: I have just installed geth on the linux platform, but I still can not walk it through, any detailed instructions? thank U