# How to encrypt messages to an account owner with the Ethereum public key?

Tags: accounts, dapps, encryption, whisper, public-key

As I understand it, an Ethereum account is a public/private key pair.

Is it possible to encrypt a message with the public key (how?) that only the account holder can decrypt it with his private key?

You could establish a forum where you could post such messages, for example to PM an account holder.

Comment: Sorry, mistook this for a duplicate of [How can I sign a piece of data with the private key of an Ethereum address?](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/693/87) in first place. But you are asking the other way around, very interesting question and welcome to Ethereum Stack Exchange!

Comment: Does duplicate look good?

Comment: This should not be mark as a duplicate. The link to the answer is not answering anything but self promote his package!