# How to generate signature & validate signature offline w/o using web3

Tags: web3js, ethereumj, signature, python, encryption

I just need a simple way to sign a message offline, preferably using Python or JavaScript.
I **don't** want to have to sign in using **Web3**. I just want my private key to be used from a variable in the code.

This is only for a proof of concept tool that I'm making, which is why I don't want to use Web3 or any nodes to do this. Is there such a library that will let me *sign & verify* a message the same way an Ethereum nodes would?

Comment: web3.py's [`w3.eth.account.sign()`](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/web3.eth.account.html#web3.eth.account.Account.sign) does what you're looking for. Unfortunately, it's only accessible by installing from source, at the moment. It is scheduled to be released as beta in the next week or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is a possible [duplicate](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/693/how-can-i-sign-a-piece-of-data-with-the-private-key-of-an-ethereum-address/704). However, I think this code may be helpful for your POC i.e. signing and verifying messages without the use of Web3js.

Using Java, the [ECKey.java](https://github.com/ethereum/ethereumj/blob/165fe6060ca40325debcc3356b02c634f1f945ee/ethereumj-core/src/main/java/org/ethereum/crypto/ECKey.java) class in [EthereumJ](https://github.com/ethereum/ethereumj) gives you all the required functionality. Here's an example of it in practice...

Signing:

```
public void testEthereumSign() throws IOException {
    ECKey key = ECKey.fromPrivate(privateKey);
    System.out.println("Secret\t: " + Hex.toHexString(key.getPrivKeyBytes()));
    System.out.println("Pubkey\t: " + Hex.toHexString(key.getPubKey()));
    System.out.println("Data\t: " + exampleMessage);
    byte[] messageHash = HashUtil.sha3(exampleMessage.getBytes());
    ECDSASignature signature = key.sign(messageHash);
    String output = signature.toBase64();
    System.out.println("Signtr\t: " + output + " (Base64, length: " + output.length() + ")");
    assertEquals(sigBase64, output);
}
```

Verifying:

```
public void testVerifySignature1() {
    ECKey key = ECKey.fromPublicOnly(pubKey);
    BigInteger r = new BigInteger("28157690258821599598544026901946453245423343069728565040002908283498585537001");
    BigInteger s = new BigInteger("30212485197630673222315826773656074299979444367665131281281249560925428307087");
    ECDSASignature sig = ECDSASignature.fromComponents(r.toByteArray(), s.toByteArray(), (byte) 28);
    key.verify(HashUtil.sha3(exampleMessage.getBytes()), sig);
}
```

Python with **[pyethereum](https://github.com/ethereum/pyethereum)**:

`sign(key, network_id=None)` - signs the transaction with the given key

> `sha3(data)` - computes the SHA3 (or more precisely, keccak256) hash
>
> `ecrecover_to_pub(hash, v, r, s)` - recovers the public key that made
>   the signature as a 64-byte binary blob of encode_int32(x) +
>   encode_int32(y). Hashing this and taking the last 20 bytes gives the
>   address that signed a message.
>
> `ecsign(hash, key)` - returns the v, r, s values of a signature
>
> `normalize_key(key)` - converts a key from many formats into 32-byte binary
>
> `privtoaddr(key)` - converts a key to an
>   address

Comment: Thank you. Is there a js or python implementation of this readily available?

Comment: @Raven yes! Please see updated question for python.